# Identify set(s) based on open bags

Tags: set-identification

How can we identify these Lego bags?

It has 2017 year on the bags. Also, there are five random pieces of bags. Most of those pieces yellow and orange colors [image]

Answer (score 3):

Since at least some of these bags have been opened, their contents no longer help us in determining which set(s) they were from. At this point, they are just random plastic bags. You have combinations of elements in these bags that do not exist as combinations of pieces within one single set, for example in the top-left bag (with #2 on it) you have both a 2x8 Brick in Dark Bluish Gray as well as a 6x5 Girder in Yellow. Those pieces have never been in a set together (the Brick in Dark Bluish Gray only ever came in 2 sets).

Comment: Came to the same conclusion, some of the combinations are simply not possible according to bricklink... Also, some elements lead to sets that definitely would not have their bags numbered (sets too small/easy for that)...